# Отправка E-Mail из программы

Tags: c#

Привет HashCode, скажите как можно например при нажатии на button1 произошла отправка сообщения на test@test.ru с сообщением : "бла бла бла бла текст"?

Answer (score 4):

[MSDN - SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx)

Там подробно рассказано про работу с SMTP протоколом, и есть пример кода отправки письма.

Answer (score 0):

в обработчик события click для кнопки :

```
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.To.Add("адрес получателя");
            mail.Subject = "тема письма";
            mail.Body = "текст письма";
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.ru", 25);
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("адрес отправителя", "пароль отправителя");

            client.EnableSsl = true;

        try
        {
            client.Send(mail);
        }


        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.Source);
        }
```